# GC collects a still referenced object

Tags: vb.net, excel, garbage-collection, vba

I need to solve a mathematical model for concentration in a particle and excel is the UI for the parameters.

I made a dll library in vb.net that has 3 classes: Particle, ParticleMix
InteropParticleMix.

Particle based on it's properties have a sub that calculates the concentration in the next step by a simple euler method.

ParticleMix is a class that have a dictionary of Particle, double representing the mass fraction of each particle in the mixture and properties calculating the weighted average of the properties.

InteropParticleMix inherits ParticleMix, it creates 3 Particles on creation saving them on 3 fields. In a Sub called Load I add the 3 particles on the dictionary with respective fractions. And last but not least, a function that loops n times calling the next step by a simple euler method saving the concentration of each particle and the average in an array.

Now from VBA-excel I create a new InteropParticleMix, insert every property and call the iterative method storing in a variable that makes a plot.

Everything great with the mathematics and info flow, but 30% of the time the returned value goes nuts. The firsts elements of the array always work, but a random particle goes in a random point to 6553500. I'm assuming this is caused by the GC collecting one of the particles during the iteration. This behavior is for the same input parameters so it's not a divergence or rounding problem.

Already used GC.KeepAlive method on every particle before, inside and after the loop. Any lights?

Comment: Smells like an overflow somewhere. Keep in mind VB6/VBA integers are only 16-bit.

Comment: The GC isn't collecting anything that is still referenced. Not sure that overflow is likely, since VB is checked by default. Either way, a description of your code is inadequate. Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @helrich I'm sure it's not an overflow. As I said, the SAME parameters as input return different outputs. The value i'm observing is a null reference.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot I can't show the code as it is, since it's for a company, but i can show the plot for the same input parameters if that helps.

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/krLYwiHlY.png - Working
http://pasteboard.co/22Mfg3MWg.png - Not Working
http://pasteboard.co/krN0ywkNd.png - Not Working 2

I didn't change any parameters, just run the same macro.

Comment: Unless you forgot the [[piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html)] tag, this is still unanswerable without your code.

Comment: If you have a null reference, the program would crash instead of giving you weird numbers.

Comment: @Comintern Well, I will write a program with the same characteristics if that's the case.

Comment: @the_lotus So, what it is with the value that returns?

Comment: OK, I made an alternative program and the result is: I can't reproduce the error with a same characteristics implementation. Since I can't show the actual code cause of copyrights, that's the best I could do. Thanyou for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. For better performance some of the properties in the classes were using a parallel.foreach loop to calculate a weighted arithmetic mean on a dictionary of Keys, weight. Example:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Test As Double
    Get
        Dim dblTest As Double = 1

        Parallel.ForEach(MassFractions.Keys, Sub(s)
                                                 dblTest += s.Test * MassFractions(s)
                                             End Sub)
        Return dblTest
    End Get
End Property
```

But for some reason, this leads to some unexpected behaviour on event listeners and references. Changing to a not parallel loop solved the issue. Solved example:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property Test As Double
    Get
        Dim dblTest As Double = 0

        For Each s As Substance In MassFractions.Keys
            dblTest += s.Test * MassFractions(s)
        Next

        Return dblTest
    End Get
End Property
```